# Какие есть алгоритмы шифрования изображений, устойчивые к трансформации?

Tags: фурье, fft, изображения, wavelet, шифрование

Какие есть алгоритмы шифрования изображений, устойчивые к изменению размера изображения, поворотам на углы, кратные 90 градусам?

Т.е. зашифровал исходное изображение - оно на себя не похоже, набор узоров, загрузил на фотохостинг, где его в т.ч. уменьшили. Взял уменьшенный вариант, и тем же ключом расшифровал в уменьшенную копию исходной картинки. Есть такие решения?

В идеале — вообще зашифровали - распечатали - сфотографировали на мобильник распечатку - дешифровали в исходное, пусть такого же уменьшенного разрешения и плюс искажения перспективы. Т.е. решение, не привязанное жестко к пикселам, и к точным значениям цветов/яркостей.

**Upd.** как шаг к анонимности интернетов в эпоху тотального контроля государств и корпораций, имеет смысл добиваться такого вида зашифрованного изображения, что автоматическими методами сложно провести его связь с исходником. Т.е. например, [гистограмма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) зашифрованного никак не должна кореллировать с гистограммой исходника. Например, если порезать картинку на блоки и переставить их местами, гистограмма никак не изменится. Если канал инвертнуть, гистограмма его просто отзеркалится. Поэтому, повторю, интересно услышать тех, кто работал с FFT ([быстрое преобразование Фурье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C1%FB%F1%F2%F0%EE%E5_%EF%F0%E5%EE%E1%F0%E0%E7%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5_%D4%F3%F0%FC%E5)) и [вейвлетами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82).

Comment: Я бы поставил на то, что нету: алгоритмы шифрования рассматривают файл как бесструктурный поток битов. А почему фотохостинг уменьшил зашифрованное изображение? Или вы дали ему расширение как будто это картинка?

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен watermark: метод прятать информацию внутри картинки так, чтобы при обработке её можно было бы всё равно считать. Таким образом внутрь картинки-контейнера можно положить любую информацию, не только картинку. Не забывайте, однако, что размер картинки-контейнера при таком подходе должен быть существенно больше размера картинки, которую вы прячете.

Comment: Я думаю, можно что-то придумать, только с изменением размера будут проблемы. Спасибо за интересную задачку :) Если найду решение, отпишусь.
@VladD, никто же не заставляет брать бесструктурный поток битов, можно орудовать с изображением – как с матрицей.

Comment: То есть решение бы разделилось на 2 независимые части: обыкновенное шифрование, и упаковка в картинку так, чтобы зашифрованная часть не терялась при преобразованиях.

Comment: Не вникал подробно, но с помощью wavelet'ов, вроде бы можно "узнать" картинку при разных размерах и поворотах, даже с добавленным шумом.

Comment: Можно попробовать костыли: задать изображение числом или строкой, затем применим шифрование для строки, затем что-то типа qr кода. Правда размер получившееся изображение будет иметь ...

Comment: опять таки, вы говорите о растровом изображении, на котором не используется алгоритм сжатия с потерями. случае необходимости уменьшить размер изображения, как поступать будете(да еще с учетом применения стандартных форматов представления, а не чего-нибудь экзотического)? в .bmp все хранить? )

Comment: @Bars: по факту, современные криптоалгоритмы (DES/3-DES, RSA, AES, Twofish, Serpent) шифруют именно поток битов. Это, в принципе, не обязательно, но надёжных алгоритмов, основанных на свойствах картинок, пока не разработано. В частности потому, что задача имеет меньшее прикладное значение, чем задача шифрования потока битов.

Comment: Перечитал задачу. Да, я не совсем отвечаю на вопрос «какие есть алгоритмы», а предлагаю его разработать. Все же несложно:

 • берем матрицу пикселей и ключ;

 • переводим ключ в целочисленную последовательность;

 • в соответствии с ключом, к примеру, меняем пиксели местами;

 • получившуюся матрицу преобразуем в изображение.


При дешифровке инвертируем ключ и проводим те же операции.
Я бы сварганил, да сейчас времени нет.

Comment: @Bars: фишка этой задачи именно в отстраивании от пискелей. Чтобы даже если изменить размер "зашифрованного" изображения, его было можно дешифровать тем же ключем, пусть, в уменьшенный вариант исходной картинки. Т.е. точно не пиксели и значения яркостей. FFT или вейвлеты.

Comment: Ну и ладно, пусть это будут не пиксели (как абсолютно позиционированные точки), а блоки относительных размеров – суть не меняется. В таком случае будет определяться нижний порог размера. То есть, к примеру, зашифрованную картинку можно уменьшить максимум в 4 раза. Если уменьшить ее в 5+ раз, то дешифровка будет невозможна (ну или даже возможна, но с сильными искажениями).

Еще мешает то, что алгоритмов уменьшения картинки очень много.

Comment: Алгоритмы уменьшения, и ещё варианты компрессии. Но это уже область допиливания. Лишь бы например, переживал ВКОнтактовское уменьшение и ресэмплинг.

Comment: точно непомню но кажется алгоритм коха-жао устойчивый к разного рода преобразованиям и трансформациям

Comment: (Комменты под моим ответом переполнены)
@sergiks, не расскажешь, в чем суть твоего метода «как можно обратимо искажать картинку до неузнаваемости»? Интересно же! Если, конечно, это еще не является коммерческой тайной в рамках Google Inc :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPD [2013-02-07]** [Новый алгоритм «Chan»](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php)

Не оставляет меня в покое эта тема. Написал новый алгоритм шифрования.

**Алгоритм работает очень долго,** посему просьба не тестировать на больших картинках и набраться терпения: кнопки «Encrypt» и «Decrypt» понимают с первого раза, не стреляйте в них очередью.

Примеры:

1. [Оригинал](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360272671.jpg)
2. [Зашифрованное изображение](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360272671-encoded.png)
3. [Расшифрованное изображение](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360272701-decoded.png)
4. [Расшифрованное с неверным паролем](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360273325-decoded.png)

Основан на преобразовании цветов пикселей, но работает весьма неплохо, на мой взгляд.

Недостатки:

- шифрование слишком слабое; перебо́ров за 10–20 можно подобрать такой пароль, который даст представление о содержании изображения (хотя цвета могут быть искажены)
- JPEG-компрессия сказывается на расшифрованном изображении (появляется рябь), поэтому на тестовой странице я выдаю результат в PNG
- очень много коллизий ключей
- очень медленно, необходимо оптимизировать

Положительные черты:

- устойчивость к любым трансформациям (кроме цвета), будь то поворот/разворот или даже посторонние данные, например:
- [Исходное](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360274312.jpg): зашифрованная ранее картинка находится на нормальной (к примеру, фото плаката с изображением зашифрованной фотографии)
- [Расшифрованное](http://bars.koding.com/oxy_image/chan_crypt.php?action=view&image=keu4kljuqpvshcoksqe21dkjt6-1360274312-decoded.png): зашифрованная картинка «распаковалась»

Есть идея добавить свойство `(bool) loseless`, в зависимости от которого алгоритм и, соответственно, результат, будет меняться:

- при `loseless = on` – будет работать как сейчас;
- при `loseless = off` –  шифрование будет значительно надежнее, но с потерей двух цветов: `0xFFFFFF` станет `0xFFFFFE`, а `0x000000` – `0x000001` (то есть, и в зашифрованном и в дешифрованном абс. белый и абс. черный будут отсутствовать).

Или можно не заморачиваться и прописать `loseless = off` как единственный вариант.

[[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks), а у тебя как дела с этой задачей?

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**UPD [2013-01-30]** [Новая версия алгоритма «мозаика»](http://bars.koding.com/mosaic/mosaic_crypt.php)

---

Доделал вот прототип: http://image.lotoflot.com/mosaic_crypt.php

Выдерживает повороты кратные 90 град., но с изменением размера беда: очень сильные искажения после дешифровки.

**Удачный пример**

1. [Оригинал](http://image.lotoflot.com/tuh83tqb0iv09lgrok3070dbk7-1356751296.jpg)
2. [Зашифрованное изображение](http://image.lotoflot.com/mosaic_crypt.php?action=view&image=tuh83tqb0iv09lgrok3070dbk7-1356751296-encoded.jpg)
3. [Расшифрованное изображение](http://image.lotoflot.com/mosaic_crypt.php?action=view&image=tuh83tqb0iv09lgrok3070dbk7-1356751587-decoded.jpg)

Лавина хорошая благодаря md5. Ключ внутри функции раскладывается на составляющие, каждый из которых хешируется. Для нормальной работы нужен массивный набор данных (а не 2-3 символа), поэтому решил не изобретать и подключить md5.

Параметр *Pieces* определяет, на сколько кусков в обоих направлениях (X, Y) будет порезана картинка. Чем больше значение, тем больше блоков. Обычно лучше устанавливать значение в диапазоне 10—30 для картинок размера 300—2000 px.

Я как-то давно на PHP начал писать класс-прослойку для GD. Так вот эти функции шифровки/дешифровки я запихнул в класс расширения этой прослойки, так что код будет слегка запутанным. Но если все же заинтересует, могу поделиться.

Comment: Класс! Плюс в карму, что заморочился сделать прото. Минус этого метода, что гистограмма картинки идентична исходнику. Даже инверсия каналов не избавит от этого. С FFT (fast Fourier transform) не экспериментировал?

Comment: Не с FFT не экспериментировал. Я вообще это преобразование не понял, а эти сраные окна Ханна и прочих молодцов и вовсе мне мозг съели. Тогда я возился с аудио-потоком, а как разложить на гармоники 3-канальное изображение – понятия не имею.

А почему гистограмма идентичная? Там же и не все, и не половина секций инвертируется, а строго в зависимости от ключа.

Comment: Проверил гистограмму. Отличается, хоть и не слишком сильно: [пруф](http://image.lotoflot.com/histogram-test.jpg)

Comment: да, с фрагментарной инверсией получается отличная гистограмма. Поиграть с FFT можно в [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). В сети много уроков, как убирать повторяющийся узор / муар из изображений с помощью FFT. Из исходной картинки получается две квадратные, ч/б, чуть бОльшего размера, чем исходная.

Comment: С уменьшением вносятся искажения: [скриншот](http://pix.am/r25b/) Понятно, что это связано с трансформациями положения пикселей.

Comment: Да, я об этом писал: "с изменением размера беда: очень сильные искажения после дешифровки". Но эту ошибку можно исправить путем добавления избыточности: при шифровке не просто резать на мозайку, а захватывать бОльшие площади для каждого кусочка. Тогда даже если и будут искажения, то они будут не так заметны: будут не черные полосы, а дублирующиеся "строки" и "колонки" пикселей.

Comment: @Bars, как ваша идея, не развивали? У меня появилась мысль, как можно обратимо искажать картинку до неузнаваемости, но всё ещё не сделал proof-of-concept.

Comment: Забыл, но сегодня проверил почту и увидел ваш коммент — вспомнил :)
Доделал чуток. Чуток изменил порядок перестановок: раньше куски не смещались более чем на -2..2 позиции, теперь гуляют по всему полю. Еще добавил избыточность 50%, так что, теперь зашифрованное изображение становится больше в 2 раза (+рамка с меткой поворота).
Вот результат: http://bars.koding.com/mosaic/mosaic_crypt.php

Comment: @Bars хотел посмотреть реализацию, но ссылки не работают в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретных алгоритмов не скажу, но наверняка они есть. Наверное надо копать в сторону именно графической шифровки, к примеру поставить точки которые организуют квадрат чтобы уйти от зависимости от ориентации картинки, и внутри этого генерировать данные которые представляют исходную картинку. самое тупое - например точка 2x2 или 3x3 - 1, нет такой точки - 0. Можно наверное более сложно придумать - яркая точка начала, от неё рисовать примитивы - линия под углом - определённый набор битов (например угол задаётся исходным куском битов, цвет каждой следующей линии - следующая пачка данных) ну и т.д. Ваша задача - графически представить нужные вам данные - как - простор для фантазии.

Так же можно использовать тупо набор известных вам однозначно обратимых фильтрах (сдвиги, повороты и т.д.) которые Вы применяете в определённом порядке, а для расшифровки - в обратном (например картинку сдвигает на 10 пикселов, поворачиваете на 15 градусов, сдвигаете на 3 пиксела вниз, инвертируете цвета, сдвигаете цвета на 20, меняете каналы местами и т.д.).

Comment: Первый затык - преобразование изображения, которое не зависит от его размера. Зашифровали большую картинку. Шифрованный вариант уменьшили и повернули. И даже из этого треша, с правильным ключем восстановили исходное изображение, пусть, и мЕньшего размера, чем исходник.

Таким образом, привязка к пикселям отпадает. К меткам 2х2 / 3х3 тоже.

Comment: Метка 3х3 будет устойчива к уменьшению в три раза. А из точки как ни шифруй, исходное изображение не получить.Привязка к точке - яркая точка занимающая N пикселей, при уменьшении не исчезает а уменшается. Заметьте я не написал пиксел, а именно - точка.

Comment: Точка - не пиксел - ОК. Подход с точками по углам близок к QR. Видимо, надо копать в сторону распознавания графических образов. Что хорошо распознается - переводится в биты - дешифруется.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал копать в сторону стеганографических трюков с изображениями, когда модифицируется наименее значимый бит (LSB) пикселя или что-то подобное. Обзор некоторых из таких методов [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography_tools)

Наиболее перспективный для вас метод на мой взгляд это *redundant pattern encoding*, то есть когда шифровка размещается не по всему изображению, а дублируется в нескольких частях (pattern), так что при обрезке изображения останутся кодированные куски из которых можно будет восстановить сообщение.

Теперь рассмотрим способ восстановления исходного шифросообщения после изменения размера изображения (паттерна). Здесь может помочь один из алгоритмов избыточного кодирования, например [метод Хамминга](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) или что-то подобное. Благо таких способов довольно много, надо просто задаться процентом сколько бит надо уметь восстанавливать из потерянных - это чуть ли не целая отрасль математики.

Comment: Спасибо з аответ и ссылку на Хамминга. Стеганография тут непричем, т.к. объём информации по сути равен всему изображению. И хочется устойчивости не то, что к LSB модификации, а более жесткому: снял на пленку-проявил-напечатал в журнале. В теории : )

Поэтому рою в направлении преобразования типа частотного разложения, преобразования Фурье, вейвлетов. Но опыта в вышеперечисленных - только чисто прикладной с частотным разложением в шопе.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы так быстро отказались от шифрование данных каждого пикселя независимо друг от друга? Изменения размеров и артефакты сжатия такому методу не страшны. Я, обдумывая ту же идею, склонен предполагать, что можно найти достаточно устойчивый (к взлому) шифр. Но так как в области криптографии моих знаний ноль, с этим вопросом я и пришёл сюда.

Comment: Смысл моего вопроса в том, что зашифрованное изображение должно "читаться" оптически: распечатали «зашифрованный» плакат, повесили на стене. На него посмотрел чел через Google Glass, ввёл правильный ключ, увидел скрытое изображение. Под любым углом, с любого расстояния.

Comment: Ну так шифруя цвет пикселей, вы как раз и добиваетесь этого эффекта. Я сейчас в этом вопросе пока остановился на генерации цвета на основе псевдослучайных чисел. С некими изначальными параметрами генерируем последовательность, которой XOR-им значения rgb каждого пикселя. Зная параметры генерации можно сделать обратный XOR, не зная - не угадать.

Comment: Если бы так всё просто было! Цвета после шифровки, печати, фотографирования, будут уже совсем другими. Мелкие пиксели могут пропасть или внести ошибку (гвоздь в плакате, пыль на матрице). Изображение может слега размыться, потеряв все мелкие детали (частотное разложение - остался только низкочастотный канал).
Поэтому я ищу такое преобразование исходного изображения, при котором можно оперировать не пикселями, а некими абстрактными от них свойствами.

Comment: Я так понимаю, смысл кодировать изображение именно в том, что потери несущественны (до тех пор, пока трансформация изображения минимальна). Пока крайне интересно видеть что получается на входе и выходе в работах, где реализован метод шифрования детерминированным хаосом. Жаль не встретил ни одной с изменением размера.

Comment: Нда, задача все усложняется и усложняется по мере обсуждения: сначала нужен был алгоритм, устойчивый к изменению размера изображения и поворотам на углы, кратные 90 градусам, а теперь надо еще и продольные искажения учитывать, и игнорировать "нецелостность"...

Думаю, тут на такой вопрос ответа не найдешь, ибо те, кто такой алгоритм сделали/сделают, пойдут с патентом прямиком в Гугол с этой своей разработкой :)

Из дешевых вариантов я вижу только raw-шифрование с последующим преобразованием в какой-нибудь 2D штрих-код

Comment: @Bars, давай скооперируемся и пойдём в Гугол : ) Серьёзно. Нашёл каких-то немцев, похожую тему развивали, но недалеко ушли. Написал им.

Comment: Давайте найдём решение, которое способно сохранить качество картинки как у оригинала, но быть доступным к дешифровке при изменении размера.

Comment: @sergiks, ты меня прямо за живое схватил, я уже неделю над этой твоей задачей думаю, спать стал плохо )Я все еще в поисках. Думаю, развивать ли тот алгоритм. Как сделать его более устойчивым к изменению размеров - вроде придумал. Плюс: этому алгоритму плевать на гвозди в плакате, они просто так и останутся помехами на декодированном изображении (этого даже может и не произойти - смотря, где гвоздь). Проблема в том, как рассчитать skew.

Comment: Какой алгоритм то?

Comment: @trashmajor, http://hashcode.ru/questions/177825#178748

Comment: Придумал, как можно усовершенствовать QR-code, увеличив его вместительность, в 3 раза :)